# JDBC doesn't return more than 2,1 billion records from SELECT

Tags: java, ojdbc

I read records from Oracle table throught JDBC. Table contains about 2,3 billion records. JDBC returned me only max. 2,1 billion records. It seems that the JDBC returns max count equivalent to max integer (2,147,483,647). The processing ends with no errors.

I use Oracle 11g (release 2) in combination with ojdbc7. I tried some setting around fetch size (in jdbc or/and in java code) - I've never get more recs than integer max size.

I use standard java code for read from db. All saved records in output file are correct.

```
java.sql.Connection conn_tOracleInput_1 = null;
String driverClass_tOracleInput_1 = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
java.lang.Class.forName(driverClass_tOracleInput_1);

String url_tOracleInput_1 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address=(protocol=tcp)(host="
                + context.COM_SERVER
                + ")(port="
                + context.COM_PORT
                + "))(connect_data=(service_name="
                + context.COM_SERVICE_NAME + ")))";
String dbUser_tOracleInput_1 = context.COM_LOGIN;
String dbPwd_tOracleInput_1 = context.COM_PASSWORD;
java.util.Properties atnParamsPrope_tOracleInput_1 = new java.util.Properties();
atnParamsPrope_tOracleInput_1.put("user", dbUser_tOracleInput_1);
atnParamsPrope_tOracleInput_1.put("password", dbPwd_tOracleInput_1);

conn_tOracleInput_1 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url_tOracleInput_1, atnParamsPrope_tOracleInput_1);
java.sql.Statement stmtGetTZ_tOracleInput_1 = conn_tOracleInput_1.createStatement();

/* setting time zone */
java.sql.ResultSet rsGetTZ_tOracleInput_1 = stmtGetTZ_tOracleInput_1.executeQuery("select sessiontimezone from dual");
String sessionTimezone_tOracleInput_1 = java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
while (rsGetTZ_tOracleInput_1.next()) {
   sessionTimezone_tOracleInput_1 = rsGetTZ_tOracleInput_1.getString(1);
}
((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn_tOracleInput_1).setSessionTimeZone(sessionTimezone_tOracleInput_1);

java.sql.Statement stmt_tOracleInput_1 = conn_tOracleInput_1.createStatement();
String dbquery_tOracleInput_1 = "SELECT ident, end_date, change_date FROM REPO.EMPLOYEE";

java.sql.ResultSet rs_tOracleInput_1 = null;
try {
  rs_tOracleInput_1 = stmt_tOracleInput_1.executeQuery(dbquery_tOracleInput_1);
            rs_tOracleInput_1.setFetchSize(context.FETCH_SIZE);

String tmpContent_tOracleInput_1 = null;
while (rs_tOracleInput_1.next()) {
  ProdCharValStruct prod_char_val = new ProdCharValStruct();

  if (rs_tOracleInput_1.getObject(1) != null)
    prod_char_val.ident = rs_tOracleInput_1.getBigDecimal(1);
 ....
/* write into file */
}
```

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to the query. 2.3 Billion row lol

Answer (score 4):

## 32-bit limits common

Java was invented back in the days of [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) [machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit#Architectures). So you will find many limits within the Java libraries based on 32-bits. As you mentioned, a 32-bit `int` or `Integer` in Java is limited to [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE): 2^31-1, or 2,147,483,647.

For example, look at the JavaDoc for your call to [`ResultSet::setFetchSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()). That method takes an `int`.

While I have not yet found specific documentation, I would expect a cursor in [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to have a 32-bit limit of approximately 2.1 billion rows.

In practice, a limit of 2 billion is reasonable. As emeraldjava commented on the Question, dealing with billions of rows at a time is not likely to be practical. Add a filter to your query such as a WHERE clause, to work with a meaningful subset of rows.